# Вызов метода WCF-сервиса всегда возвращает NULL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

Добавляю сервис в проект по сгенерированной wsdl, которую получаю от коллег. Мне в Web.config генерируется endpoint и binding к нему.

- При попытке вызвать метод сервиса, получаю в ответ null.
- При попытке вызвать тот же сервис на тот же endpoint через SoapUI я вижу response о том, что сервис принял мой реквест и вернул сообщение с успешным статус-кодом.

Пробовал логгировать события WCF-там так же вижу этот ответ с успешным статус-кодом. Из этого я делаю вывод, что проблемы с десериализацией сообщения. Могут ли это быть неверно сгенерированные reference.cs файлы? В какую сторону нужно копать?

Comment: А родной студийный WcfTestClient как себя ведёт, интересно?

Comment: Ведет себя так же как и код. Когда смотришь ответ в XML, то ответ есть. А когда смотришь в форматированном виде - ответ NULL

Comment: Ну, наверное, правда проблемы с десериализацией, но конкретнее не подскажу (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге проблема была в неверно сгенерированной WSDL. Помогло добавление аттрибутов IsNullable = false на сгенерированную модель в Reference.cs